Converting float64 array to uint16 (Python)
I'm having trouble in a data type conversion from float64 to uint16. If I have an array of floats  and I try to convert it with
array_uint16 = array_float64.astype(np.uint16)

is there a sort of "built-in check" that already converts all values greater than (2^16-1) to the max of the range supported by uint16 or do overflow problems occur?
Thank you

From simple experimentation using default casting='unsafe' it looks like it truncates to integer modulo 2**16, e.g. int(n) % 65536, so 65537.8 -> 1.  If you don't understand, them make a [mcve] and explain your expectation vs. what you received.

Since you want to get saturating behavior (instead of wrapping as @MarkTolonen suggested), you can just numpy.clip your values before converting - it's explicit and should not be a performance bottleneck (unless you know it is, then at least ask a question with more details to share your observations - perhaps there is some more clever way).

@STerliakov I wasn't suggesting anything, just describing the "built-in" current behavior.  OP didn't actually describe desired behavior, which is why I asked for an [mcve].

You can use numpy.clip() before converting:
import numpy as np

# Example array
array_float64 = np.array([-1, 0, 100000, 65535, 65536], dtype=np.float64)


# Clip values
necessary_type = np.uint16
min_value = np.iinfo(necessary_type).min # 0
max_value = np.iinfo(necessary_type).max # 65535
array_clipped = np.clip(array_float64, min_value, max_value)


# Convert to uint16
array_uint16 = array_clipped.astype(necessary_type)
array_uint16
# array([    0,     0, 65535, 65535, 65535], dtype=uint16)

This ensures values above 65535 are set to 65535 and values below 0 are set to zero
Here is a doc and here is a related question
